# No app name on Facebook app posting - "shared a link via ."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use my Facebook app for posting and while I post the display name is missing in the status.

See the following example:

> XXX XXX shared a link via .

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` appearing instead of the name of the app is a **bug**.

You can track this here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/640453342670536/

So its nothing your fault. Just wait till it gets fixed!